# Databinding JQuery UI DatePicker

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

i am unable to get the jquery ui datepicker to show data correctly.

My input Date string to databind is

> 10/1/2015 12:00:00 AM

Date Picker Declaration goes as

```
$("#jquidtp").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "../Content/images/Tools/calender.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Select date",
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy"
});
$('#jquidtp').mask('99/99/9999');
```

Code to Data bind is

```
$('#jquidtp').datepicker().datepicker('setDate', new Date(k));
```

The bound textbox shows

> 01/10/20152015

whereas the desired output should be

> '01/10/2015'

What am i missing ? Any help is appreciated.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to jQuery UI [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate) you should use `dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"`

> y - year (two digit)
>
> yy - year (four digit)